# Accepting an int or an object in ASP.NET endpoint

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I have a few endpoints in my ASP.NET 5 API that contain embedded many-to-many relations. For example the `/widgets/1` GET endpoint would return something like

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "creators": [
        { "id": 1, "name": "Mad Scientist" },
        { "id": 2, "name": "Crazy Scientist" }
     ]
}
```

For the corresponding PUT request I would like to accept both of the following two versions:

```
{
    "name": "foo edited",
    "creators": [
        { "id": 1, "name": "doesn't matter" },
        { "id": 2, "name": "doesn't matter either" },
        { "id": 3 }
     ]
}
```

and

```
{
    "name": "foo edited",
    "creators": [1,2,3]
}
```

In both cases only the ids would be used, I'm not trying to allow editing the creators through this endpoint. The only thing you should be able to do here is to link widgets to existing creators.

The version with only ids in a list is the most convenient if you have a list of creators from somewhere else and just want to attach them to your widget. The main reason to support the first version with a list of objects is to allow a user of the API to GET a widget, modify the widget and send the modified version back via a PUT request.

I don't want to just declare this as object and examine the types at runtime. Ideally at model binding or deserialization the integer would simply be converted to the object with the id set and everything else null.

As far as I found, there is no out-of-the-box way to do this, I have to customize some part of either model binding or JSON deserialization (System.Text.Json in this case). But most of what I found require me to handle the entire entity, which I don't want to override. I only want to modify the behaviour for the "creators" property of my entity, everything else should work with the defaults. I'm simply not sure where the proper place to hook into is for this use case. And additional aspect is that I'd like to have this in a generic way, as I have similar cases in a few other endpoints.

What is the least invasive way to insert this behaviour without affecting the handling of the other properties of that entity?

Comment: If you force `"creators": [1,2,3]` to be sent as `"creators": [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]` then the problem becomes a much easier to solve. Make a DTO with optional `name` (and other) property. If only `id` is defined, fetch the record, if all fields are defined, create a new record.

Comment: @abdusco that is my backup plan if this turns out to be infeasible.

Comment: You can write a custom model binder to read the json into a DTO class, but how would that class look? Specifically, `creators` property? How do you define a collection type that can either accept an `int` or a `CreatorDto`? (You don't want to accept a `List<object>`)